# OpenCV: Fill in missing elements in CVMat with avg of nearest non-zero neighbors?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

The basic problem is this:

I have a CVMat, type CV_8UC1, which is *mostly* filled in with integers (well, chars, actually, but whatever) between 1 and 100 inclusive.  The remaining elements are zeros.

In this case, 0 basically means "unknown".  I want to fill in the unknown elements with, essentially, the average of its nearest neighbors... i.e. if this matrix were representing a 3d surface with a bunch of holes in it, I want to smoothly fill in the holes.

Keeping in mind, of course, that it's possible there are some rather big holes.

Efficiency isn't *super* important, as this operation is only going to be happening once, and the matrix in question isn't bigger than around 1000x1000.

Here's the code I need to finish:

```
for(int x=0; x<heightMatrix.cols; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<heightMatrix.rows; y++) {
        if (heightMatrix.at<char>(x,y) == 0) {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this instead:

put your data in an image and use image closing with a large kernel (or with a lot of iterations):
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html#morphologyex

Comment: Thanks; however, problem with using averages like this is that if there are other zeros nearby, the zeros wind up "in the mix".  Also, when there are larger areas of contiguous zeros this method winds up being *extremely* slow.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
int sum = 0;

... paste the following part inside the loop ...

sum += heightMatrix.at<char>(x - 1,y);
sum += heightMatrix.at<char>(x + 1,y);
sum += heightMatrix.at<char>(x,y - 1);
sum += heightMatrix.at<char>(x,y + 1);

heightMatrix.at<char>(x,y) = sum / 4;
```

Since you deal with a CV_8UC1 Mat you have in practice a 2d array and each pixel has just 4 nearest neighbors.

There are some caveats however:

1)    put your averaged pixel in a Mat of floats to avoid round off!

2)    to fill the whole Mat with this average may not be what you are looking for if   the non-zero pixels are quite sparse: when there is a lot of empty pixels and really few non-zero pixels the more you move away from a non-zero pixel, the more the average converges to 0. And this may happen in as few as 3-4 iterations (another good reason to store not to store the values in a Mat of integers).